# Google Contacts API - First name and Last name of some contacts are missing even if it is there in my google contacts

Tags: php, google-contacts-api

There are some contacts for which google contacts API does not return first name and last name.

Strange thing is that it is showing the first name and last name when I go to my google contacts, But even when I export the contacts from the google contacts screen first name and last name are missing for some contacts.

Screenshot 1: My google contacts screen

[image]

Screenshot 2: Exported CSV of Contacts

[image]

Same thing happens with API. For Contact Jim Smith, API does not returns the first name and last name.

[image]

I am using google contacts API version 3. Here is output XML:

```
<entry gd:etag='"SH08eDVSLit7I2A9XRFRFkkOTwQ."'>
    <id>
        http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/topslivewire%40gmail.com/base/5f4ec6148922d762
    </id>
    <updated>
        2016-08-31T12:00:09.370Z
    </updated>
    <app:edited xmlns:app="http://www.w3.org/2007/app">
        2016-08-31T12:00:09.370Z
    </app:edited>
    <category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind" term="http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#contact">
    </category>
    <title>
    </title>
    <link href="https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/topslivewire%40gmail.com/5f4ec6148922d762?v=3.0" rel="http://schemas.google.com/contacts/2008/rel#photo" type="image/*"/>
    <link href="https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/topslivewire%40gmail.com/full/5f4ec6148922d762?v=3.0" rel="self" type="application/atom+xml"/>
    <link href="https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/topslivewire%40gmail.com/full/5f4ec6148922d762?v=3.0" rel="edit" type="application/atom+xml"/>
    <gd:email address="ami.bhatti@tops-int.com" primary="true" rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#other">
    </gd:email>
</entry>
```

For Contact Ami Bhatti, API does not returns the first name and last name.

The sorting issue for "Other Contacts":

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please show code showing how you're making a request. If I had to guess, you're probably unintentionally using v1 of the API, which does not return structured names. A typo in setting the version (in either the header or params) would not throw and error and instead default to version 1 instead of version 3.

Comment: @BlakeO'Hare I have updated question. I have used google contacts API version 3.

Comment: That output has the first and last name.

Comment: Yes but for some contacts, API doesn't return that field even if there is first name and last name exist. Attached snapshots in question - For Jim smith is doesn't return first name and last name. Even when I export contacts from google contacts screen, first name and last name for some contacts are blank.

Comment: But can you show the API output for those contacts that aren't working? I wanted to check for other red flags on the erroneous contact such as FileAs being present.

Comment: @BlakeO'Hare updated the post. Ami Bhatti is showing in google contacts but in API output only email address is there. Please look at XML.

Answer (score 0):

If I type `ami.bhatti@tops-int.com` into the user search bar in hangouts, I can see "Ami Bhatti" pop up, which means the name is coming from the profile, but the actual contact you have there has nothing other than the email itself. The Contacts API does not join information from the user's profile aside from profile picture whereas the web UI does.

If you want profile information in addition to the manually-entered contact information, you may consider using the People API instead (although it only supports read-only operations at this time): https://developers.google.com/people/

Comment: ...and as further confirmation, the same goes for jim Smith, who shows up with a lowercase "j" and an uppercase "S" in the web UI just like yours, when I give just the email.

Comment: @black-ohare First name sorting is not working properly in "Other Contacts"  of google contacts.

Comment: Any updates on sorting issues in gmail/inbox contacts?